# How to avoid updating selenium webdriver for every firefox versions

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

How to avoid updating selenium WebDriver for new Firefox versions

I am using Selenium Webdriver and a Firefox version for testing.

Selenium:-

```
https://github.com/vertis/selenium-webdriver
```

Selenium is updated based on the Firefox version. Every time, I have to match the versions of Selenium and Firefox version to work with. How to avoid updating the version.

I have found some info about this here :

```
http://makandracards.com/makandra/1575-how-to-install-a-frozen-version-of-firefox-for-your-selenium-tests
```

Anyone know solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of firefox, newer versions of Selenium is required. If you want to avoid changing selenium version, simply stop update on firefox.

Go to tools --> Options --> Advanced --> Update and check Never check for updates.